# How to get the number of people in the household? and Linguistically homogeneous households?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

There is a dataframe I have to get the **Number of people in the household** and **and Linguistically homogeneous households?**

```
df <- data.frame(
        Village = c(rep("1", "30")),
        Number = c(33,  33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 1,  1,  30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30,
                   31,  31, 31, 31, 36, 36, 36, 36, 62, 62, 62, 62, 69, 69),
        Number_1 = c(183,   183,    183,    183,    183,    183,    183,    151,    151,    255,    255,    255,    255,    255,    255,
                     255,   31, 31, 31, 31, 111,    111,    111, 111, 287, 287, 287,287, 219, 219),
        Number_3 = c(137,   137,    137,    137,    137,    137,    137,    113,    113,    191,    191,    191,    191,    191,    191,
                     191,   23, 23, 23, 23, 83, 83, 83, 83, 215, 215, 215, 215, 164, 164),
        PERSNUM = c(1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,
                    1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3,  4, 5,  1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
        DAILY_LANG = c(33,  33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  11,
                       11,  11, 11, 11, 11, 0,  0,  11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11))
```

How many household speak in one **Language**? the **DAILY_LANG** variable is the language code. I need find how many of families speak in one language and how many speak in 2 language.

Note: this question **How to get the number of people in the household?** answered. just need on find the ** Linguistically homogeneous households?**

Much appreciate for your answer

Comment: It's not obvious to me how family size is defined in your input data.  Please give your *expected output* based on your input data.  Also, it would be helpful to have your input data as the output from `dput`.  It's easier to import and therefore we can spend more time helping other people.

Comment: As you know the size of families are different. I want to get how many families are 3 people. As you see on data  the two families size are 3 people.

Comment: I forgot how to **dput** the data.

Comment: As *I* know?  No, I don't know.  You may know - it's your data set - but I don't.  I don't see that there are two familes of three people.  Does that come from `PERSNUM`?  You don't tell us that.  I can *assume* that, but I don't *know* it.  And in that case, what are the `NUMBER_<x>` columns?  Based on what you've told us, they could be related to family size is some way...

Comment: **PERSNUM** is the  families numbers **1 is husband, 2 is wife, 3 is the first child and so on**. I want to just count the number of families that have just three members.

Comment: as you see on my data two families members are **Three persons** otherwise there are three 3.

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: @timey, I have add a reproduceable data and tried to make  more clear the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by columns, check if the maximum PERSNUM is 3 or 4:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Village, Number, Number_1, Number_3) %>% 
  filter(max(PERSNUM) %in% c(3, 4))
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   Village, Number, Number_1, Number_3 [2]
#   Village Number Number_1 Number_3 PERSNUM
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 1           31       31       23       1
# 2 1           31       31       23       2
# 3 1           31       31       23       3
# 4 1           31       31       23       1
# 5 1           62      287      215       1
# 6 1           62      287      215       2
# 7 1           62      287      215       3
# 8 1           62      287      215       4
```

And to check if they speak 1 or 2 languages:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Village, Number, Number_1, Number_3) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(DAILY_LANG)) %in% c(1, 2))
```

Comment: much thanks, I will active the answer tick. Just waiting for second part of question.

Comment: @Kian do not keep changing your question, if you have a new question, then ask as a new question. Do not edit, editing is for clarifying the exiting question, not completely rewriting it.

Comment: I have no permission to ask new question. I have a dataframe that need to get the Households that have at least one member of a ethnic (77).  There five columns **NUMBER, Number_2, Number_3, PERSNUM, and ETHNIC** Three of Number columns are households have to group.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear which column you want to count. But here is a general answer to your problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  foo = c(rep("a",5), rep("b", 5)),
  bar = c(1,1,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,3)
)

print(df)
#>    foo bar
#> 1    a   1
#> 2    a   1
#> 3    a   1
#> 4    a   3
#> 5    a   3
#> 6    b   1
#> 7    b   1
#> 8    b   3
#> 9    b   3
#> 10   b   3

result <- df %>%
  group_by(foo) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(bar == 3))

print(result)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   foo   count
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 a         2
#> 2 b         3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I have added the screenshot you maybe it is more clear.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear. It's a simple problem, but it gets complicated if you don't manage to formulate it.

Comment: Please run this one: ```df <- data.frame(
        foo = c(rep("a",10), rep("b", 10)),
        bar = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3)
)``` There are five families. two of them have four four members and other three families have three three members.

Comment: if I just count 3 there are five threes.

Comment: I need to get the families that have just 3 members.

Comment: @timey, I have add a reproduceable data and tried to make more clear the question.